# How to get the detailViewController to display the detailItem of the previous or next row in its masterViewController.tableView in Swift?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, core-data, master-detail

So I'm developping an image browser for iOS in Swift.

I download a list of pictures off of the Internet and present these with details in an UITableView which belongs to my MasterViewController.

By selecting a row, one gets a bigger view of the picture but if I want several successive pictures, I always have to get back to the MasterViewController and touch a new row.

What would be the simplest way in Swift to swap the currently displayed detailItem with the previous or next NSManagedObject?

At this time I tried to make my MasterViewController a property of the detailView, then ask it about its selected row's IndexPath, then incrementing it and forcing the new object to be my detailViewCotnroller's detailItem but I get crashes...

If I could also get to browse the pics using left-right or top-bottom gestures it'd be even better.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT:** I tried to implement the following but it doesn't get anything:

```
    @IBAction func older() {
        browse(1)
    }

    @IBAction func newer() {
        browse(-1)
    }

    func browse(i: Int) {
        if let o = self.masterViewController?.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!.indexPathByAddingIndex(i)) as? NSManagedObject {
            self.detailItem=PicWrapper(object: o)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

1. Make the full list of pictures available to your second view controller. You do that by adding an NSArray to detailViewController.h with all the data you need. Then you add a swipe gesture to loop through that NSArray
2. You create a protocol in the detailViewController. Then you set the presentingViewController as the delegate of the detailViewController. Now you can add a method that on swipe, the presentingViewController can send the new data to the detailViewController.

Comment: Thanks I'll try ASAP, most probably the first version, I think... I am not too fluent with Swift protocols..

Comment: Cool. If you are using AFNetworking (you should) there is a helper class called AFnetworking+UIImageView and had a method called `imageWithUrl`. If you used that in your table and then again in your detailViewController it will do a lot of caching for you out of the box

Comment: HEy thanks but as I say: I'm storing security cams pics so they come from protected URLs and I already made my app to handle these.